# Validar el día en un campo input text para que sólo acepte números entre 1 y 31

Tags: javascript, validación

Validar un día puede ser algo sencillo cuando se trata únicamente de validar números pero puede tener mucha complicación si queremos validar posteriormente una fecha válida. Por ejemplo, 30 de Febrero no puede existir.

En este caso quisiera validar un campo `input text` sólo numérico con valores entre 1 y 31, ambos inclusive.

**Código Javascript:**

```
    //Validar el dia.
function validacionDia(event){
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var value = document.getElementById("iddia").value;
    var dia = value + String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (isNaN(dia) === true || dia < 1 || dia > 31) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="2" name="dia" id="iddia"/>
```

¿Por qué me deja escribir números superiores a 31? Cuando escriba un 4 o un 6 o un 9 debería no dejarme escribir el segundo dígito, así mismo si escribo un 3 y los siguientes dígitos son cualquiera menos el 0-1.

**Código asociado al evento:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
miformulario.dia.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
        return validacionDia(event);
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: ¿Puedo solucionar tu problema desde un punto de vista diferente o debo usar tu pseudocódigo obligatoriamente?

Comment: puedes usar patrones en javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937408/regular-expression-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript

Comment: Las expresiones regulares no solucionan su problema @JackNavaRow

Comment: Todas las opciones que se entiendan o comprendan son validas. En programación nunca existe una única solución.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Mi problema no es de patrones, sino de un único campo, cual ya tengo validado para que sólo acepte números pero ahora el problema viene a la hora de evaluar las diferentes opciones que puse en el pseudocódigo.

Comment: Lo siento, por un problema con el editor de código he perdido el trabajo, tardaré otro rato en responder :(

Comment: Hecho. Por un error en copiar/pegar creé una recursión infinita al comprobar el día (y llamarse a sí mismo) que me hizo empezar de cero todo :( Para el teclado es mejor `onkeyup` que `onkeypress`. Mi respuesta muestra cómo obtener el día más alto que puede tener el año y mes seleccionado, además, hace comprobaciones en cadena (si se cambia el año se reevalúa el mes y día y si se cambia el mes se reevalúa el día, así al llegar al día se certifica que habrá un valor correcto).

Comment: También he implementado un control que impide valores que provoquen un `NaN` en el campo numérico, rechazando la pulsación de tecla en dicho caso, pero permitiendo poner valores intermedios de edición hasta que salgamos del campo. Tal y como te dicen, lo mejor es usar un campo de tipo `date`. Por último te explico las alternativas en HTML5 y jQuery :) espero que te sea de utilidad mi respuesta :)

Comment: @omaza1990 Por favor, al crear nuevas etiquetas, sería bueno cerciorarse de que no existan otras que ya se utilicen para lo mismo. Recientemente creaste las etiquetas [tag:validar] y [tag:validacion] (sin tilde), cuando ya existe la etiqueta [tag:validación]... Al ingresar las etiquetas de una pregunta, se sugieren las posibles sobre las que ya existen.

Answer (score 1):

Tras debatir en el chat acerca de la funcionalidad deseada, éste es el resultado:

```js
function validacionDia(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  /* Observamos el resultado que generará la tecla */
  var día = parseInt(
    miformulario.dia.value +
    String.fromCharCode(key)
  );
  /* Si no está dentro de lo esperado cancelamos la pulsación */
  if (
    isNaN(día) === true ||
    día < 1 ||
    día > 31
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="miformulario">
  <input type="text"
    name="dia" id="iddia"
    onkeypress="return validacionDia(event)" />
</form>
```

---

**Respuesta original**

He usado una funcionalidad que te provee el objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) en el que si indicas un día 0 te selecciona el último día del mes anterior y, además, te permitiría tener días de más del soportado por el mes incrementando internamente el número de mes y/o año.

```js
function comprobar(obj, tecla) {
  switch(obj.name) {
    case 'año':
      var año = parseInt(obj.value);
      if (isNaN(año)) {
        obj.value = 2017;
      } else if (año < 1970) {
        obj.value = 1970;
      } else if (año > 2018) {
        obj.value = 2018;
      }
      return comprobar(document.f.mes);
      break;
    case 'mes':
      var mes = parseInt(obj.value);
      if (isNaN(mes)) {
        obj.value = 5;
      } else if (mes < 1) {
        obj.value = 1;
      } else if (mes > 12) {
        obj.value = 12;
      }
      return comprobar(document.f.día);
      break;
    case 'día':
      if (obj.value === '' && tecla === true) {
        return true;
      }
      var día = parseInt(obj.value);
      var último = new Date(
        parseInt(document.f.año.value),
        parseInt(document.f.mes.value),
        0
      ).getDate();
      if (isNaN(día)) {
        if (tecla === true) {
          return false;
        } else {
          obj.value = 8;
        }
      } else if (día < 1) {
        if (tecla === true) {
          return false;
        } else {
          obj.value = 1;
        }
      } else if (día > último) {
        if (tecla === true) {
          return false;
        } else {
          obj.value = último;
        }
      }
      break;
  }
  return true;
}

function enviar() {
  alert('Fecha: ' +
    document.f.año.value + '-' +
    document.f.mes.value + '-' +
    document.f.día.value
  );
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="f" onsubmit="return enviar()">
  <input type="number" name="año"
    min="1970" max="2018" value="2017"
    onblur="comprobar(this)"
    onchange="comprobar(this)"
  />
  <input type="number" name="mes"
    min="1" max="12" value="5"
    onblur="comprobar(this)"
    onchange="comprobar(this)"
  />
  <input type="number" name="día"
    min="1" max="31" value="8"
    onblur="comprobar(this)"
    onkeyup="return comprobar(this, true)"
    onchange="comprobar(this)"
  />
  <input type="submit" value="Mostrar fecha" />
</form>
```

Teóricamente habría que restar uno al mes en curso, pero como `Date` cuenta enero como `0` y diciembre como `11` no es necesario hacerlo.

Hay que tener cuidado al usar el evento `onkeyup` porque no permite escribir un número desde una cadena vacía a menos que desarrollemos esa excepción.

Como nueva edición he desarrollado esa excepción, evitando la pulsación de una tecla que provoque que el valor sea `NaN` (letras, por ejemplo), o se salga de los límites, pero no repone el valor máximo, mínimo o por defecto hasta que salgamos del campo.

Por último, prácticamente todos los navegadores compatibles con HTML5 soportan el campo [`<input>` de tipo `date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

En ese enlace se muestran todos los problemas que te puedas encontrar con el uso de dicha etiqueta (como mostrar fechas localizadas) e incluso usos para solicitar rangos de fechas admitidos:

```html
<input type="date" min="2010-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
```

Pero si usas jQuery te recomiendo usar su widget [`datepicker`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) que soluciona compatibilidad con navegadores y localización a través de su propiedad [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```js
$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({
  regional: 'es',
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script><script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-es.js"></script>
<div id="fecha"></div>
```

PD: He agregado el atributo `regional` para que los textos aparecieran en castellano.

Comment: Aunque creo que el OP no lo menciona, ¿tu código valida años bisiestos?

Comment: La duda ofende :P :) Es tan fiable como sea la implementación del objeto `Date`.

Comment: Te sugiero des soluciones exactas al problema y luego si lo consideras puedes sugerir soluciones mejores al problema, Saludos!! ;))..

Comment: @fwBasic, he dado solución exacta a la primera parte de su pregunta y solicité permiso para implementar la segunda sin seguir su pseudocódigo. Fue aceptada y así lo hice. Gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente rutina valida que coloquen un numero entre 1 y 31, utilizando el evento `onKeyPress` en cualquiera de sus variantes:

**html Tag:**

```
<input onKeyPress="..">
```

o **javascript Event:**

```
document.geElementById("IdName").addEventListener("keypress",
 [ funtionName | function () {..}])
```

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("iddia_addEventListener")
 .addEventListener("keypress", validacionDia);

function validacionDia(event){
 var key = event.which || event.keyCode,
  value = event.target.value,
  n = value+String.fromCharCode(key);
 if ( isNaN(n) || n<1 || n>31)
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
Validar dia (de 1 a 31)<br>
<br>
Usando onKeyPress=".."<br>
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="2" name="dia" id="iddia" onKeyPress="validacionDia(event);"/>
<br><br>
Usando addEventListener("keypress", [ funtionName | function () {..}])<br>
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="2" name="iddia_addEventListener" id="iddia_addEventListener" />
```

te sugiero uses ***html5*** que incluye un campo tipo fecha, es muy sencillo usarlo, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```html
<input type="date">
```

Espero esto te ayude... Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Si lo que quieres es solo validar el día aquí te dejo una rutina que lo hace pero si lo que quieres es validar una fecha campo por campo te sugiero utilices la rutina que @Oscar te ha dejado, sin embargo te sugiero menejes las fechas en un solo campo, en Internet encontraras rutinas de como validarlas, e incluso ya html5 incluye un campo de fecha muy bueno Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Funciona perfectamente sólo que tuve que poner n>0 porque sino cogía el valor 0 como día.

Comment: Que bueno, me alegra te haya funcionado y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: +1 html5 al incorporar el campo de tipo fecha elimina grandes problemas de validar "hardcode" la información suministrada.

Comment: @fwBasic Tengo una duda a la hora de implementarlo con el addEventListener, no me funciona con este evento.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta para manejar el evento `onKeyPress` en cualquiera de sus versiones, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría es que nada mas poner el número, si este es mayor de 31, se cambie el número a 31, lo veo más intuitivo que el resto de soluciones, nada mas verlo en funcionamiento te das cuenta de que es el máximo del número.

Y de la misma manera para valores menores a 1, ya que al tratarse de un día es imposible

```js
var box = document.querySelector("#input");

box.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    if(Number(box.value) > 31){
      box.value = 31;
    }
    else if(Number(box.value) < 1){
      box.value = 1;
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```